# Django Authentication process

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I noticed that when I logged in as administrator, I don't need to reauthenticate when I access non-admin area.

However, when I login as simple user and access admin zone, Django, of course, checks whether I am admin.

Where this check occurs? I want to restrict access of moderators to non-admin part of site, so need to check that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`@user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def not_staff_user(user):
    return not user.is_staff

@user_passes_test(not_staff_user)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

If you want to restrict ALL pages except `/admin/` then middleware is a good option:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class NonStaffMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_staff and not \
               (request.path.startswith('/admin/') or
                request.path.startswith(settings.LOGIN_URL) or
                request.path.startswith(settings.LOGOUT_URL)):
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

Comment: Not very handy as I need to check this in every view. I think changes should be made in Middleware.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue as redirect to login page doesn't logout. However, I got the idea. Also, I don't like the idea of hardcoding request.path.startswith('/admin/')

Answer (score 0):

You have the [user.is_staff](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff), [user.is_superuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_superuser) and [user.is_authenticated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) functions to check this wether in your views or templates. If you need to do this in your templates, the user is in the `{{ request.user }}` and also in your views with `request.user`.

Comment: Not very handy as I need to check this in every view. I think changes should be made in Middleware.